# ¿Como puedo insertar varios datos de diferentes tablas a un campo de otra tabla en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos "Cafeteria" con cuatro tablas principales "menu","cliente","menu_has_cliente" y "orden" en la tercera están las llaves foráneas para conectar a los múltiples clientes que piden múltiples alimentos de la tabla menú siendo una conexión de varios a muchos (n:m). Espero que hasta aquí me hayan entendido, lo que quiero hacer es insertar los datos de todos los alimentos que ha pedido un cliente en un campo llamado "pedidos" de la tabla "orden" compuesto por los siguientes campos idOrden,nombre(del cliente),pedidos,total y fecha... hasta ahora he podido hacer la inserción de dichos datos pero en mi tabla "orden" campo "pedidos" solo me muestra un producto aunque el cliente haya pedido varios. Eso si, me muestra el total correspondiente y se crea una fecha automática el único problema es que no me muestra todos los datos.Por favor ayúdenme! :)

Comment: ¿De donde sacas los productos? ¿Como haces el insert? Falta mucha información para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Hola Fabian, tendrias que poner informacion, las tablas, datos, que intentas, asi por lo que veo , si decis que solo te inserta uno tal vez sea porque ejecutas el insert una sola vez en vez de hacer un while por el total de datos que recibes y asi hacer todos los insert, pero como te dije antes, subi mas info porque si no es imposible ayudarte.